# Pascal. Поиск минимального элемента дерева и его уровня

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Почему в процедуре **Minimums** не происходит вход в цикл поиска минимального элемента(**min**) и его уровня (**g**)? И как это исправить?

```
const Max=10;
type
MyElement = ^PElement;
Pelement = record
  number: integer;
  left: MyElement;
  right: MyElement;
end;
var
  numbers: array[1..Max] of integer = (7,5,9,3,1,10,6,8,4,2);
  PRoot: MyElement;
  min: integer;
  
procedure Paste (var PRoot: MyElement; x:integer);
begin
  if (PRoot = nil) then begin
    New(PRoot);
    PRoot^.number := x;
    PRoot^.left := nil;
    PRoot^.right :=nil;
  end
  else
    if (x < PRoot^.number) then
      Paste(PRoot^.left,x)
    else
      Paste(PRoot^.right,x)
end;

procedure print(Root: MyElement; g: byte);
begin
  if (PRoot = nil) then
    writeln('Дерево пустое.')
  else
    if (Root<>nil) then begin
     for var i:=1 to g do
       write(' ');
       writeln(Root^.number);
       print(Root^.left, g+1);
       print(Root^.right, g+1);
     end
     else begin
       for var i:=1 to g do
         write(' ');
         writeln('*')
     end;
end;

procedure minimums(Root: MyElement; g: byte);
begin
  if (PRoot = nil) then
    writeln('Дерево пустое.')
  else
    begin
     min:=999;
     for var i := 1 to g do begin
       if min > Root^.number then
         g:= g+1;
         min:=Root^.number;
            writeln(min);
            writeln(g);
            end;
     end;
end;

procedure del(var PRoot: MyElement);
begin
  if (PRoot <>nil) then begin
    del(PRoot^.left);
    del(PRoot^.right);
    dispose(PRoot);
  end;
end;

begin
PRoot := nil;
for var i := 1 to MAX do
Paste(PRoot, numbers[i]);
var com:=0;
while true do
  begin
  writeln('-------------------------------------------------');
  writeln('1 - Вставка элемента в дерево.');
  writeln('2 - Вывод (печать) дерева.');
  writeln('3 - Очистка дерева.');
  writeln('4 - Вывод элемента с минимальным ключом и его уровня.');
  writeln('5 - Выход.');
  writeln('-------------------------------------------------');
  write('Введите команду: ');
  readln(com);
  case com of
    1: begin
       var num: integer;
       Writeln('Введите значение нового узла: ');
       Readln(num);
       Paste(PRoot, num)
       end;
    2: begin
      writeln('');
      print(PRoot, 0);
    end;
    3: begin 
        del(PRoot);
        writeln('Дерево успешно очищено.');
       end;
    4: minimums(PRoot,0);
    5: exit else writeln('Неверный номер операции!');
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: А что компилятор говорит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure mins(Root: MyElement; g: byte);
begin
  if (PRoot = nil) then
    writeln('Дерево пустое.')
  else
    if (Root<>nil) then begin
      if Root^.left = nil then begin
        writeln('Минимальный элемент: ',Root^.number);
        writeln('Уровень: ',g);
      end
      else begin
        mins(Root^.left, g+1);
      end;
    end;
end;

    **Вызов функции в Case**

    4: mins(PRoot, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы вызываете эту процедуру с аргументом 0

```
minimums(PRoot,0);
```

Соответственно, `g` в процедуре равно `0`. А значит, цикл

```
for i := 1 to g do begin
```

не выполняется

Comment: Но даже если я делаю так: minimums(Proot, 10) всё равно ничего не выводится

Comment: А что-нибудь выводится? Ошибка например?

Comment: У меня есть [немного исправленный код](https://pastebin.com/w7EkmaaC) (из-за ошибок), выводит что-то

Comment: Уже исправил, сейчас обновлю вопрос.